# Converting a list<int> into a list<float>? c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

on multiple lines(20+), I know what this error means so I changed all of my int declarations to float but this didn't change where the error was appearing so I had a look at the lines and noticed it was to do with a list declaration I had in a different class.

the error appears on lines like this one:

```
graph = new Node[widthX, heightY];
```

It says the error is on `widthX` and `heightY` but both are declared as floats, graph however is declared as:

```
Node[,] graph;
```

Which is a different class and inside it is a list which I think, is where the root of this error is actually coming from. The code of that class looks like this:

```
public List<Node> edges;

public Node(){
    edges = new List<Node> ();
}
```

After reading up on C# I saw a lot of converting from string to int or int to string or double to int etc, but nothing on floats.

Or I'm reading this error incorrectly in which case I have no idea where its coming from.

Comment: arrays can't have fractional length...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `widthX` and `heightY` in your array declarations, if they are not integers. If that makes sense, you have to cast them to `int`.

```
var graph = new Node[(int)widthX, (int)heightY];
```

Comment: yeah that looks to have been the issue. I read the error incorrectly this fixed it though thanks!

Comment: I'll accept this when I can as the answer(10 minute delay).

Comment: @ParagonTime You are welcome. I am glad that I helped.

Comment: `(int)Math.Ceiling(widthX)` would be better than just adding 1.

Comment: The first part of the answer is correct; the second part (beginning with "I think that...") is utterly wrong.  And so is the comment suggesting to use `Math.Ceiling()`.  A simple cast to `int` will give you the floor of the float, (provided that the float is positive,) which is usually what you want. If you are sure you need rounding to the nearest int, then you should use `Math.Round()` and *then* cast to `int`.

Comment: @MikeNakis I just corrected it.